# Delete a domain from localdomains with CPanel API?

Tags: php, cpanel

We're using CPanel servers and I developed a DNS Editor with CPanel API: 
http://docs1.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/XmlApi

Now I have the Problem that when change the MX records of a domain which is installed on a CPanel account, the domain will still be listed in /etc/localdomains.

Is there a way to delete that entry with cpanel API?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The domain will be added to /etc/localdomains (local) or /etc/remotedomains (remote) based on the MX record, and this is updated as needed whenever the MX entry is modified. The domain name should be automatically removed from /etc/localdomains if you set remote MX record.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the api2 it worked fine with it.